# GridView Header Text in asp.net using asp:BoundField

Tags: asp.net, gridview, data-binding, boundfield

I want to change the header text of the gridview using Design..

```
<asp:BoundField HeaderText="">
```

i created a variable in javascript  and initialize variable defending on the condition  and then i tried to call that variable over here as below:

```
<asp:BoundField HeaderText="Text Here" DataField="slno" >
```

here I use "text here" string stored in one variavble name . and i want to use that variable

My code :

```
 <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
 /// <summary>
 /// TO ACCESS COOKIE VARIABLE
 /// </summary>
 var flag;
 var ca = document.cookie.split('=');
 for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0) == ',') c = c.substring(1);
}
if (c != '' && c != null) {
    flag = c;
}
else {
    flag = 1;
}
//*********************************************
if (flag == 1) {
    var name_lbl = "Hai";
}
else if (flag == 2) {
    var name_lbl = "How are you?";
}
</script>
//------------------------------------------------
</asp:Content>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
</table>

<div style="overflow: auto; height: 99%;" id="divTable">
<table><tr><td>
<label for='field ID'>&nbsp;<b><input type="text" id="kilist_lbl" size="20"         style="border: none; height:20px" readonly/></b>&nbsp;&nbsp;</label> <br />
</td></tr></table>

<asp:GridView ID="gvareadetails" runat="server"  
CssClass="mGrid"  AutoGenerateColumns="False">
<Columns>        
  <%-- here is the problem when assigning ID to headerText label --%>
     <asp:BoundField HeaderText='sss' DataField="slno" >  
    <ItemStyle Width="5%" />
    </asp:BoundField>
 </Columns>
 </asp:GridView>
 </div>
 </form>

 <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
 document.getElementById('sss').value = name_lbl;
 </script>

 </asp:Content>
```

Any one have any suggestions how this could be achieved..

Comment: This has nothing to do with [tag:asp-classic]! Please re-tag with [tag:asp.net]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of js, just try the C# code to get values from the grid view.

ex:

```
int name_lbl = gvareadetails.Columns[0][0];
```

Here `Columns[0][0]` gives you the first row first column value.

Comment: gives error:
Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataControlField

Comment: String sss="Hai"; 
gvareadetails.Columns[0][0].HeaderText=sss;

Comment: String name_lbl ="hai"; name_lbl= gvareadetails.Columns[0][0]; also gives the same error

Comment: Thanks Shaji SS; It works for me, but with little modification in your code; I appreciate your suggestion saying that "Instead of js You just try the C# code to get values from the grid view.." Thank You

Answer (score 0):

C# code to get values from the grid view:

```
    string name_lbl;

   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
    //---------------------------------------------
    /// </summary>
    /// /// <summary>
    /// TO ACCESS COOKIE VARIABLE
    /// </summary>
    string b;

    HttpCookie a = Request.Cookies["LangaugaeObj"];
    if (a != null) b = a.Value; else b = "1";

    if (b == "1")
    {
        name_lbl = "Hai";
    }
    else
    {
        name_lbl = "How are you";
    }
    //---------------------------------------------------
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      // here I set the variable name to the grid Header
       gvareadetails.Columns[0].HeaderText = name_lbl;

       Report report = new Report();        
       report.areaid = hidStatus.Value.ToString();

       DataSet ds = report.getareawisedetails();

       gvareadetails.DataSource = ds;
       gvareadetails.DataBind();


       ds.Dispose();
       ds = null;
       report = null;
    }
```

Thank You for Shaji SS for his suggestion.. I hope this answer will help to someone who looking for- set the header text dynamically in asp.net using asp:BoundField.